# Ionic2 - Error - If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm not sure to understand the error I'm getting while looping through an array of options to populate my select list.

Here is the error I get

```
Error in ./PhonePage class PhonePage - caused by: 
If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the 
form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.   
Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first"> 
Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Here is my html code

```
<form>
    <h2>Quel est votre numéro de téléphone?</h2>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col width-33>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="optionList">
                            <ion-option *ngFor="let item of optionList" value="{{item.text}}">{{item.text}}</ion-option>
                        </ion-select>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ngForm is used, all the input fields which has [(ngModel)]="" must have a attribute name with a value.

Answer (score 2):

Prerak Tiwari's answer is correct.

Here is just a little tip: I see you bind your ion-select to "optionList" but this is just the list of options you want to show and need to create all ion-options.

You should bind the ion-select to a new parameter, because aftewards it will hold the selected ion-option.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think she messed up the code in order to resolve the posted issue. She used the correct identifier in the earlier question. Nice catch.